# Inconsistent method result in node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, eventemitter

I have been trying to figure the following for the last couple of days and just can't seem to figure out the answer. I am new to node and JS (only experience is online tutorials).

I am trying to create a class (function) to scrape the source code from websites. I want to read in a url from the command line and return the html content. However, I seem to be getting different results when running the code different ways (which I think I should be getting the same results).

I have been reading about events in node and so I have used them a little in the code. One listener event prompts the me for the url and then after setting the url it (the listener function) emits a message, which is picked up by another listener which goes out and fetches the html content.

The problem I am having is that when I create an instance of the object, it seems like the request portion of the code does not execute. However, if I call the method from the instance I get the print out of the html content of the page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function test() {
  var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
  var request = require('request');
  var util = require('util');

  var that = this;
  that.eventEmitter = new events();
  that.url = 'http://www.imdb.com/';

  that.eventEmitter.on('setURL',that.setUrl = function(){
    console.log("Input the URL: ");
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

    process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
      that.url = util.inspect(text);
      that.url = that.url.substr(1, that.url.length - 4);
      that.eventEmitter.emit('Get url html');
      process.exit();
    });
  });

  that.eventEmitter.on('Get url html',that.httpGet = function() {
    console.log("Fetching... " + that.url);

    request(that.url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
      } else {
        console.log("Error Encountered");
      }
    });
  });

  that.eventEmitter.emit('setURL');
}

var scrapper = new test(); //This asks me for the url and then only executes to first line of that.httpGet.

scrapper.httpGet(); // This gives the desired results from that.httpGet
```

Comment: Does the console.log( "fetching..." + that.url ); log on instantiation?

Comment: Yes, console.log("fetching... " + that.url); is the last thing to get printed to screen during instantiation. I don't know why console.log(body) does not get run or does not print out. It will however print out if I call it directly as scrapper.httpGet();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the Prompt library https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt

```
function test() {
  var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
  var prompt = require('prompt');
  var request = require('request');
  var util = require('util');

  var that = this;
  that.eventEmitter = new events();
  that.url = 'http://www.imdb.com/';

  that.eventEmitter.on('setURL',that.setUrl = function(){
    prompt.start();
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

    prompt.get(['url'], function( err, result ) {
      that.url = result.url;
      that.eventEmitter.emit('Get url html');
    } );
  });

  that.eventEmitter.on('Get url html',that.httpGet = function() {
    console.log("Fetching... " + that.url);

    request(that.url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
      } else {
        console.log("Error Encountered");
      }
    });
  });

  that.eventEmitter.emit('setURL');
}

var scrapper = new test(); //This asks me for the url and then only executes to first line of that.httpGet.

// scrapper.httpGet(); // This gives the desired results from that.httpGet
```

I ran the script from the commandline, input http://www.google.com and it retrieved the results without the additional call to scrapper.httpGet();

Comment: Thanks Brad. It works! Any idea why I was having the issue in the first place?

Comment: process.stdin.on('data', function (text) 

This line actually triggers the moment you type a letter in my tests. So it appears what was happening is that the first letter was canceling out all of your input and url and causing the issue. I'm not extremely well versed in Command line applications, so i opted for a library to help me. I'm sure there's ways of fixing your existing code if you wanted to remove a dependency. :)